# nine patch images are working on iphone apps

Tags: ios, nine-patch

i am making one of my iOS app an din that i want to use images that are Nine patch type so
here my question is that is there iOS support the Nine patch images?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets`

Comment: The method i posted is from the iOS-sdk, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code and specify inset spacing as per your requirement.

```
 UIImage * ninePatchImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
imageView.image = [ninePatchImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 30, 30, 30) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
```

Its works same as nine patch image of android